# How to configure flask session behind iis reverse proxy (wfastcgi)?

Tags: python, session, iis, flask, reverse-proxy

I'm configuring my flask app to run under iis with a reverse proxy. Basically my setup is like this:

```
external.domain.com:8000 -> 
Reverse Proxy IIS -> 
interal.network.net -> 
iis (wfastcgi/flask)
```

The app's urls and content is loading correctly, but anything that deals with a session is not working:

- Message flashing - no messages are flashed
- Login cookies - not able to login at all

I've configured the flask app with these relevent config variables:

```
SERVER_NAME = 'internal.network.net'
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = 'external.domain.com'
```

I have an IIS rewrite rule set up on the external server:

```
Pattern: (.*)
Rewrite URL: http://internal.network.net/{R:1}
```

Is there anything else I need to configure to get sessions working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the *correct* way of doing things but apparently excluding the properties `SERVER_NAME` and `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` actually fixes the issue.

Hope this helps someone.